# Trouble with Adding Image Upload to Existing Form

Tags: php, forms

I'm working on a classifieds I'm setting up for my site and I've found myself "Stuck" again.

I'm new to PHP but I'm working on developing a better mouse trap for the classifieds and the script I will provide below I have written entirely from scratch and it works. (uploads data to the DB) but when I add the if block starting with: if($_POST['Image 1'] != "") { the whole thing crashes. (I get a white screen with no error messages or anything).

Here's the full code for this page;

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once('z-mysql_ini.php');
    require ('z-connect.php');

    $mysql = new mysql();       

    if($_POST['Description'] != "") {
        $TypeID = $_POST['TypeID'];     
        $FatherID = $_POST['fatherID'];
        $Model = $_POST['Model'];
        $Price = $_POST['Price'];
        $Description = $_POST['Description'];
        $Year = $_POST['Year'];     
        $VIN = $_POST['VIN'];
        $Address = $_POST['Address'];
        $City = $_POST['City'];
        $State = $_POST['State'];
        $ZIP = $_POST['ZIP'];
        $Country = $_POST['Country'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Phone = $_POST['Phone'];       
        $InformOfUpdates = $_POST['Inform'];
        }   

        $node = new sqlNode();
        $node->table = sprintf("`tt_%s`", abs(intval($_POST['TypeID'])));
        $node->push("int", "CategoryID", $FatherID);    
        $node->push("int", "MemberID", $_SESSION['memberID']);
        $node->push("text", "Model", strtoupper($Model));       
        $node->push("int", "Price ($)", $Price);
        $node->push("text", "Description", $Description);
        $node->push("int", "Year", $Year);
        $node->push("text", "VIN", $VIN);
        $node->push("defined","PostDate","NOW()");
        $node->push("text","Featured","yes");
        $node->push("defined","ExpireDate","DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)");
        $node->push("text", "Address", $Address);
        $node->push("text", "City", $City);
        $node->push("text", "State/Province", $State);
        $node->push("text", "ZIP/Postal", $ZIP);
        $node->push("text", "Country", $Country);
        //$node->push("text", "Email", $Email);
        //$node->push("text", "Phone", $Phone);     
        $node->push("int", "Inform", $InformOfUpdates);

        if(($result = $mysql->insert($node)) === false) {
            echo mysql_error();
            echo 'Unable to Insert Data'; 
            } else {
                $ListingID = mysql_insert_id();
                }

                if($_POST['Image 1'] != "") {   
                    echo 'File Selected and Data set in DB';
                    } else{
                        echo 'No File Selcted but Data Inserted';

                        //header("Location:memberindex.php");
                    }
                    }               

            ?>
```

If anyone could kindly show me what I'm doing wrong that's  making the page crash, I'd be most appreciative as then I can move forward with re-implementing the image upload code that came with the classifieds, but I can't even get past this initial block of test code without the page dying (and not uploading to the DB.

Bottom line is if I take the following code off of the page entirely, the script will upload all of the variable data above into the DB but if I add this block of code the whole thing crashes.

```
if($_POST['Image 1'] != "") {   
                    echo 'File Selected and Data set in DB';
                    } else{
                        echo 'No File Selcted but Data Inserted';

                        //header("Location:memberindex.php");
                    }
```

Comment: Switch on the error reporting  and check whats the error. 
Use error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Thanks @Samy, (I think) I found a rouge curly brace.